# Problem with data into MariaDB using the SELECT clause in WHERE section

Tags: sql, ubuntu, mariadb, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I don't know how to explain but I'll try, into my database in a table, I have one record with many fields.
The username field, for example, contains the value = 'any-user-test'  but if I execute a "SELECT" clause and in the WHERE section I compare username='any-user-test' the result does not contain the record.
But if I compare using username LIKE '%any-user-test'  the record is returned.

And as further proof using:
WHERE CONVERT(username USING ASCII) = 'any-user-test'
the record is returned too.

The database is MariaDB in a server Ubuntu using encryption and CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci.

Any idea how to identify the problem?